# Call `ConcurrentLinkedQueue.poll` on empty queue seems return 0 instead of null

Tags: scala

Scala version 2.12.1-20161205-201300-2787b47

```
val max = 20
val queue = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue[Int]()
(1 to 10).foreach(queue.offer)
def show(c: Int): Unit = {
    val e = queue.poll()
    if(c < max && e != null) {
      println(e)
      show(c + 1)
    }
  }
show(0)
```

Repl output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

What happened ?

Comment: You can't assign `null` to an `Int` (it's not a reference type). So, it converts it to 0. The usage of null is discouraged in scala in general. This is one of the reasons for it. You are writing java code in scala syntax, it's not very useful. Get into the scala mindset.

Comment: @Dima Is there any scala alternative to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, `Int` extends `AnyVal`. Types that extend `AnyVal` cannot bind to a `null` value.

This code complies because there is boxing and unboxing happening behind the covers between `Int` and the `Integer` reference type. For example, to set the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` with an `Integer` instead of an `Int`:

```
def apply$mcZI$sp(x$1: Int): Boolean = queue.offer(scala.Int.box(x$1));
```

And same goes when you pull out a value via `offer`, the compiler does:

```
val e: Int = unbox(queue.poll());
```

Where `unbox` goes to `BoxesRunTime.unboxtoInt`:

```
public static int unboxToInt(Object i) {
    return i == null ? 0 : ((java.lang.Integer)i).intValue();
}
```

And that's why you see `0` instead of `null`. Be careful when doing such interop between Java classes in Scala.